# Stopping a rosbag at a certain timestamp to be compare with a modified bag

Tags: timestamp, ros, bag, rosbag

Is there a way to stop a `rosbag` at a certain timestamp? I'm trying to compare a file before and after a filter at the exact same time but I'm unable to find any!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative manner:

> Play only a certain second from the bag files with knowing the point of the desired timestamp:
>
> <sub>[Reference](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play)</sub>

```sh
$ rosbag play -u <SEC> rosbag-file.bag
```